# NodeJs + Moongose + TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

Sou novo no desenvolvimento com NodeJs e estou com um problema.

Eu tenho uma Array de um obj cujo o Id é do tipo ObjectId do mongo.

Eu estou tentando realizar um find dentro desse Array buscando esse Id. E não está funcionando. Aqui está minha tentativa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Esse _id espera uma String se não me engano. Verifica se o tipo que tu tá passando/comparando é String...

Comment: Eu converti os dois valores para String e funcionou! Se quiser responder esse pergunto dou o voto aqui. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O **_id** espera uma String. É preciso definir seu tipo como uma String.